# Why do people recommend to do server side storing of session data when we can sign and encrypt session instead?

Tags: encryption, session-cookies

Why do people recommend to do server side storing of session data if we can sign and encrypt them?

I mean isn't it almost impossible for there to be any security problem if we sign and encrypt them (therefore can just store all data in the session cookie)? Am I missing any security problem here? What else should I consider?

In short, I am asking about the pros and cons of session data storage at server side vs encrypting session cookie.

Comment: To save bandwidth.

Comment: @SLaks Doesn't sound convincing when session data is probably going to be very small? Unless you are talking about user data.

Answer (score 0):

This has one problem. Session data is sometimes large, in some cases few hundreds kb. If this would have to be sent with every request it would consume a lot of bandwidth.

However if the session data is small and there are millions of users, it can potentially lower the complexity by removing the database for handling session data.

Anyway, I haven't seen a single  website doing this.

Comment: What kind of data do people store in session that will reach few hundreds kb? For me, I just need to know whether the user has logged in, so that they don't have to log in again. Therefore, it will only contain the user id. Even if there is more data, I suspect most data will be tied to user rather than session, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

on the client side, you have to have the key in order to interact with the server (for example, update your shopping cart), then an attacker can obtain the key, decrypt it, alter it, and re-encrypt it with the key, then sent it to the server. that is the end user is the attacker.

the point of encryption is to avoid data being intercept while being transmitted, it cannot solve if the end user is hacking your site.